# "Lose not an hour" origin

Tags: etymology

The earliest use of the phrase I can find is Horatio Nelson, urging his commander, Sir Hyde Parker, to attack the combined fleets of Russia, Sweden, and Denmark, moored off Zealand.  When Parker dithered over the two choices of approach, Nelson burst out "Let it be by the Sound, by the Belt, or any other way, but lose not an hour."

His exclamation is famous, in its way, but was it original? The strange phrasing (even for 1800) suggest it was not.

Comment: I think the way this question is framed is somewhat misleading. So far as I'm aware, before [do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) became widespread in English, Nelson's usage would have been the ***norm***, not a possible ***original*** "coinage". Notice how [*lost not a moment*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lost+not+a+moment%2Cdid+not+lose+a+moment&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) has gradually given way to *did not lose a moment* over the past couple of centuries.

Comment: I wonder what other ways Lord Nelson may have had in mind. As far as I know, there are _are_ no other (sea)ways to Copenhagen than by the Sound or by the Belt (and of course, even going by the Belt also entails going by the Sound).

Comment: It's not a set phrase. It's four words of plain English put into a plain English clause in a way that was common until quite recently.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- perhaps Nelson was just frustrated or perhaps he was being thorough, in the manner of his colleague Admiral Jervis, who said the next year, "I do not say, my Lords, that the French will not come. I say only they will not come by sea."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Exactly, there are no other ways. Nelson is basically saying impatiently: "I don't care how you get there, just go!"

Comment: @Malvolio, perhaps he just assumed they'd come on the EuroStar through the tunnel. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

"Lose not an hour" does appear in literature slightly earlier:

> I conjure you lose not an hour in placing me under the sort of protection I solicited.
>
> [*The Heiress*](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/ecco/004803887.0001.000/1:7.3?rgn=div2;view=fulltext) (1786), John Burgoyne (1722–1792)

Burgoyne was an army officer (who fought in the American War of Independence) and politician as well as a playwright. That "lose not an hour" appears in a play would indicate that such phrases were not exactly uncommon.

However, Nelson's turn of phrase — taking into account the construction of the entire sentence — is poetic, rather like the memorable utterances of Churchill.

Answer (score 1):

*Lose not an hour* can be found before Nelson’s time (1758 – 1805), such as in *[The practical works of the late reverend and pious Mr. Richard Baxter](http://books.google.com/books?id=1UgjAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA358&dq=%22lose%20not%20an%20hour%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UGgvUqzQMpDOsgaf6IC4Bw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA)* from 1707:

> And doubtless this is the best way to redeem time, and fee that we lose not an Hour, when we spend it only on Necessary things : And I think it is the way to be most Profitable to others, tho* not always to be most Pleasing and Applauded; ...

However, as old-fashioned as “lose not a” sounds to our ears, it’s probably just that: old-fashioned. I don’t think it would have sounded odd in the 18th or 19th centuries.

This [Ngram chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lose%20not%20a,do%20not%20lose%20a&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) suggests “lose not a” was more popular than “don’t lose a” (and “do not lose a”) during the 19th century, plus a bit each side:

[image: Ngram chart]

(Note: Google processes “don’t lose a” as “do not lose a”.)

English has changed so that we now usually say “do not lose” or “don’t lose” rather than “lose not” (and likewise with other verbs). Remnants of the old way can still be found, for example in poetry and this from the [*King James Bible*](http://biblehub.com/luke/23-34.htm) (1611):

> Then said Jesus, Father, forgive them; for they know not what they do.

This sounds archaic (although now idiomatic) to our ears, but would have sounded normal in the 17th century. If we compare modern translations from the *New International Version* (2011) and *New Living Translation* (2007):

> Jesus said, “Father, forgive them, for they do not know what they are doing.”
>
> Jesus said, “Father, forgive them, for they don’t know what they are doing.”

Comment: Why would the _[verb] not_ construction come from a Norman French influence on English? The reduction of the _ne [verb] pas_ circumfixal negation to a simpler _[verb] pas_ type is much later than Norman times (and remains limited to colloquial language to this day), and the _[verb] not_ type of negation is the common type found in all Germanic languages except English (except, partly, Afrikaans). Additionally, your example is incorrect: ‘to not lose’ (or ‘not to lose’) is _ne pas perdre_, since _pas_ precedes infinite verbal forms. _Ne perds pas_ is ‘do not lose’ in the imperative.

Comment: @Hugo:  Don't forget "And lead us not into temptation, but deliver us from evil."